# Facebook Request FBWebDialog UI looks strange

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-requests

I'm trying to send FB requests, but the FBWebDialog renders a UI that I have never seen before.. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've checked the usual suspects:

- facebook app settings
- Bundle Identifier
- FacebookDisplayName
- FacebookAppID
- URLTypes, URL Schemes

Code I'm using to send the request:

```
- (void)sendRequest {
NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization
                    dataWithJSONObject:@{
                    @"social_karma": @"5",
                    @"badge_of_awesomeness": @"1",
                    @"request_action": @"1"}
                    options:0
                    error:&error];
if (!jsonData) {
    NSLog(@"JSON error: %@", error);
    return;
}

NSString *giftStr = [[NSString alloc]
                     initWithData:jsonData
                     encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSMutableDictionary* params = [@{@"data" : giftStr} mutableCopy];

// Display the requests dialog
[FBWebDialogs
 presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:nil
 message:@"Please send me some Energy!"
 title:nil
 parameters:params
 handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
     if (error) {
         // Error launching the dialog or sending the request.
         NSLog(@"Error sending request.");
     } else {
         if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {
             // User clicked the "x" icon
             NSLog(@"User canceled request.");
         } else {
             // Handle the send request callback
             NSDictionary *urlParams = [self parseURLParams:[resultURL query]];
             if (![urlParams valueForKey:@"request"]) {
                 // User clicked the Cancel button
                 NSLog(@"User canceled request.");
             } else {
                 // User clicked the Send button
                 NSString *requestID = [urlParams valueForKey:@"request"];
                 NSLog(@"Request ID: %@", requestID);
             }
         }
     }
 }];
}
```

The UI that I see:

[image]

Same UI, scrolled to the bottom:

[image]

The UI I expect to see (Same device using an FB Sample app):

[image]

Comment: are you using facebook.sdk??

Comment: I've added the FacebookSDK.framework, version 3.7. I also have #import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h> in my class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer.. Facebook was responding with a different UI based on the User Agent that was being sent. The code I was working with modified the user agent to add some additional info for the server. Once I reset the user agent, the usual Facebook UI was shown.